# what is $\mathcal{F}_t^0$-optional positive process $\tilde a(q)$ defined in Hayashi et al?

Tags: stochastic-processes

in the paper of [Hayashi et al.](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.1214/11-AIHP432.pdf)  in assumption D is defined the following convergence in probability $A(q)_t^n \overset{\mathbb{P}}\to \int_{0}^{t} a(q)_s ds$. what does it means the process $a(q)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t^0$-optional positive process?

Comment: It would be better to ask on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) as this question is more regarding stochastic calculus/processes. The presence of theoretical math experts on Math SE is (probably) much greater than here. You can also search for "Optional Processes" on Math SE and see what pops up.